# after which one of the verbs you use an ing verb form?

Tags: verbs

***UPDATED***: I do really appreciate your explanations and taking time. Nevertheless, none of them isn't my answer. I, again, try to explain  my specific question:

As I have already surfed the Internet and some dictionaries, I have realized the fact that, for instance  the bold part, either ing form of a verb or an infinitive with to could appear after cannot. So, I am wondering the other same rules for italic parts.

*cannot tolerate*

*cannot resist*

cannot help

**cannot bear and cannot stand both of  them need either ing form or infinitive with to**

*cannot avoid*

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question is not clear to me. Generally you wouldn't use an -ing form after 'cannot'. The phrases as you've written them are grammatically correct. For example, "I cannot tolerate boorish people." "I cannot resist chocolate." "She cannot avoid the tollway on her way home."

Answer (score 2):

The verb which follows a modal verb (*can/could*, *may/might*, *must*, *shall/should*, *will/would*) in a verb group is ***always*** a ‘bare’ infinitive—that is, an infinitive which is not ‘marked’ with *to*. (The presence of *not* or an adverb does not affect this rule.) Marked infinitives and partiples cannot occur in this position.

> <sup>ok</sup>She cannot **tolerate**<sup>bare infinitive</sup> his rudeness.
>   <sup>∗</sup> She cannot **to tolerate**<sup>marked infinitive</sup> his rudeness.
>   <sup>∗</sup> She cannot **tolerating**<sup>present participle</sup> his rudeness.
>   <sup>∗</sup> She cannot **tolerated**<sup>past participle</sup> his rudeness.
>   <sup>∗</sup> <sub>marks a form as ungrammatical</sub>

However, modal verbs can combine with progressive, perfect and passive constructions. When that is the case, it is only the **first** auxiliary after the modal which is cast in the infinitive. Subsequent auxiliaries and the main or ‘lexical’ verb take the form required by the construction. (But none of these constructions takes a marked infinitive).

> PROGRESSIVE: <sup>ok</sup>She cannot **be**<sup>bare infinitive</sup> **tolerating**<sup>present participle</sup> his rudeness.
>   PERFECT: <sup>ok</sup>She cannot **have**<sup>bare infinitive</sup> **tolerated**<sup>past participle</sup> his rudeness.
>   PASSIVE: <sup>ok</sup>His rudeness cannot **be**<sup>bare infinitive</sup> **tolerated**<sup>past participle</sup> by her.
>   PERFECT PASSIVE: <sup>ok</sup>His rudeness cannot **have**<sup>bare infinitive</sup> **been**<sup>past participle</sup> **tolerated**<sup>past participle</sup> by her.

Comment: Thanks but this is not my answer

Comment: @nima Do you mean which of the verbs you list take gerund clauses as their complements? --all of them may.

Answer (score 2):

First off, it is absolutely irrelevant if you use "can" or "cannot" before the verb, which–as StoneyB correctly pointed out–is always the bare infinitive when you use a modal verb.

However, if I understand your question correctly, you ask about how to know if you have to use the gerund or infinitive after the main verb.

I'm afraid but you have to learn them by heart. There's not even a rule of thumb. To make it worse, there are four types:

- verbs that take gerund only
- verbs that take infinitive only
- verbs that take both, with similar or identical meaning
- verbs that take both, but with different meaning

Example:
"I stopped smoking" means that you don't smoke any more; "I stopped to smoke", however, only suggests that you halted something, which is not mentioned, for a moment *in order to* smoke.

It's pretty impossible to go into details about each and every word but when search the Internet for "verb + infinitive + gerund", you often find the answer, especially for those verbs where gerund and infinitive uses have different meanings.
Additionally, you often find examples in learner's dictionaries.

Comment: +1 You understood the question better than I did. And it's even more complicated than you describe: some verbs take a *that* clause in addition to a gerund or infinitive, or instead of them.

Answer (score 0):

The verbs
*tolerate

risk

help

avoid*
are all followed by the -ing form.

Comment: I cannot *resist* pointing out that you skipped one!