# "Liz can speak" or "Liz can speaks"?

Tags: verbs, modal-verbs, singular-vs-plural

I saw in a grammar book mentioned something like this :

> Liz can **speak** French very well.

Then I saw another example saying like this :

> 1. She often **eats** durians
> 2. My mother always **wipes** the floor.

With those examples, I got a little bit confuse. Why is the 1st example not saying "speaks" as it is referring to Liz which is only 1 person? Is it because it is referring to **Proper Noun** ?

Comment: Related: [Verb forms with “I”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49792/verb-forms-with-i) and [after which one of the verbs you use an ing verb form?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/43316/after-which-one-of-the-verbs-you-use-an-ing-verb-form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The the verb in the first sentence is not *speak*, but *can speak*. *Can* is a [modal verb](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/modal-verbs) indicating ability, possibility, or permission. The exact modality can only be known with additional context.

*Can* (and *may*), when used as modal auxiliaries, are always used with the bare infinitive form of a verb, which in this case would indeed be *speak*.

> Liz speaks French very well.
>
> Liz can speak French very well[, but she did not want to embarrass her sister].

The subject being plural or a proper noun makes no difference in the form.

> The rivers can swell high with snowmelt well into the summer.
>
> Eli Manning can boast that he still has more Super Bowl MVP awards than his brother.

Answer (score 1):

It's the bare infinitive, **speak**, because the sentence uses the modal **can**.  When we use a modal like *can*, *should*, *might*, etc., we don't conjugate the verb after it.

For example,

He **rides** a bicycle.  / He **can ride** a bicycle.
She **paints** well.  / She **might paint** well.
Pat **opens** the door.  / Pat **should open** the door.

Reference: [modal verbs](http://esl.fis.edu/grammar/rules/modal.htm)